# Updating Progress Bar Value While Uploading the Image

Tags: objective-c, progress-bar

I want to update both the label and progress bar like 
Progress Label :if i uploading 5 image means 0/5 ->after one image uploaded the label should be updated as 1/5 like this ans so on at lst 5/5

i did this correctly using this code

```
self.progressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%lu",self.currentIndex,(unsigned long)self.arrayWithImages.count];
```

this will be used after successfully uploaded the image one by one .
Now i want to update the progress bar it is not updating  correctly 
i have did like this

```
           int count =   self.currentIndex++;
      self.progressView.progress =count/self.arrayWithImages.count;
```

i am updating  the current index value after successfull image uploads  one by one .
Please help me to do this .

Answer (score 0):

What type of object is `progressView`?

`NSProgressIndicator` does not have a `progress` property, it has `doubleValue`, which takes a value from 0-100

So you could try:

```
self.progressView.progress = (count/self.arrayWithImages.count)*100;
```

Just make sure that `count` is always less than or equal to `self.arrayWithImages.count`

Comment: @thanks , A O , it showing 0 value for the progress bar ,it is not updating

Comment: What type of object is `progressView`?

Comment: You named a `float`, `progressView`?  I don't think that's right because you then later on access the `progress` property, which is not something a `float` has...